# Google Maps: Using custom buttons

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, controls

Im using custom controls with **google maps api v3**.
Searching all over the web and reading the documents for the Api v3.

But i got stuck with a button, that when clicked it will not be unclicked. This is the button i click.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {                             
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON);
});
```

But when i click on an other custom button, it is still active on the previous button.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
    map.setOptions({draggable: true});
});
```

I want when somebody clicks to make a polygon, and after that he clicks on the dragable that the polygon button is unclicked and the function is reset, like a way that it is unclicked and when the user clicks it again the function is activated again.

Ik hope that i explained it, so that you understand my problem.

---

**An Update** (For not making a second question). 
I cant find the controls settings of the `redo` and `undo` events on google maps.

 The controls that should be set inside here.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
    //something like CTRL + z (on windows) redo or undo of the user steps (while drawing a polygon)
});
```

Comment: Do you want to quit drawing mode when you click on the second button? If so, than you have to use `drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);` in second event handler.

Comment: Yes! i have added that to one of my handlers and it works fine! But how to use it for the same button? So when clicked first, you can draw a polygon byut when you click the same icon again, you get `drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);` ?\

Comment: When you set up event handler, save a handle. And when activated, remove it. Something like this: `var handle = google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {                             
    google.maps.event.removeListener(handle);
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(controUI, 'click', function() {
        map.setOptions({draggable: true});
    });
});` So you immediately change it to something else.

Comment: I mixed it up. The second handler should set drawing to null. Wrong cut&paste

Comment: I figured that out, hehe. But now when clicked for the third time, it wont able drawing a polygon no more...

Comment: So, if I understand you want to switch it on/off with the same button?

Comment: Yes! Excactly, i want to have it like a boolean(true/false). AND when clicked on an other button it sets itself to false too.

Comment: You can use boolean variable in event handler and on each click change  its value. If it's true, start drawing, change value and next time stop drawing and change value. It seems it could go without removing handle.

Comment: Brilliant! Noobies that i didn't think about that! So easy, but i was thinking so hard! `var drawPoly = false;
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() { 
    if(drawPoly == false){
     drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON); 
     drawPoly = true;
    }else{
     drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
     drawPoly = false;
    } 
   });`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43380/discussion-between-c-travel-and-anto-jurkovic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from Anto Jurković i came with a solution that worked for me. After seeing the solution i felt a bit noobies, but here it is.

I needed to use a **new variable** and the `true` and `false` statements.

```
var drawPoly = false; 
google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() { 
    if(drawPoly == false){ 
         drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON); 
         drawPoly = true; 
     }else{ 
         drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null); 
         drawPoly = false; 
     } 
});
```